# Create folders for each file in the folder and name the folder from CSV using cmd or batch

Tags: csv, batch-file, cmd

My requirement is: I will have list of files in a folder, also I will have a csv /excel sheet in which I will have 2 columns

1. File Id
2. File Name (It is same file names which are in the folder).

Now I want to create a folder for each file but I want to name the folder with the File Id which is in CSV which maps with the file name.

I tried the code below:

```
@echo off

for %%i in (*) do (
 if not "%%~ni" == "organize" (
  md "%%~ni" && move "%%~i" "%%~ni"
 )
)
```

this is creating folders for each file but the folder name is taken from the file name.

What my need is:
I want the folder names to be taken from a csv file in which I have a mapping between file name and file Id as columns.

Comment: Top right of this page is an `?` icon, select it then select the `tour` link, once you have done that, follow the advice and then edit your question to make it on topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a fairly straightforward thing to do in CMD

```
@( SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
  ECHO OFF
  SET "SrcFile=C:\Some\folder\files.csv"
  SET "RootFolder=C:\Path\To\Folder"
)


For /F "tokens=1* delims=," %%A IN ('
  Type "%SrcFile%"
')  DO (
  IF EXIST "%RootFolder%\%%~B" (
    IF NOT EXIST "%RootFolder%\%%~A\" ( MD "%RootFolder%\%%~A\" )
    MOVE /Y "%RootFolder%\%%~B"  "%RootFolder%\%%~A\%%~B"
  )
)
```

Comment: Thank you so much Ben Personick you are  a champ.. I think I will need your help frequently until my learning stage completes..

Comment: Ben, is there a reason for using single-quotes and `type`ing the file, rather than just giving the filename and have `for` read it? Obviously (?) you'd need to use the `usebackq` option and enclose the name in double-quotes (in case it contains spaces etc.). Is this just your "style" or is there some "corner case" that using `type` gets around?